# Checkbox selects as per tr click

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code, when you click on the first `<td>`, it's checkbox gets selected. But my goal is `checkbox` should get selected by tr click. So when I click on any `<tr>` its `checkbox` will be selected. To do this I already tried to replace on click class ".checktd" to ".odd" but this does not work.

Any idea how can I achieve that?

```js
$(".checktd").on("click", function(e) {
  if (this != e.target) {
    return;
  }
  var check = $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]");
  check.prop('checked', !check[0].checked);
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table style="width:40%">
    <tr>
      <th>Check</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Telephone</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="checktd"><input type="checkbox" class="checkItem"></td>
      <td>Bill Gates</td>
      <td>55577854</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="checktd"><input type="checkbox" name="checkItem"></td>
      <td>Kevin Gates</td>
      <td>544444</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kjr27r2j/) link if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Modify the `this!=e.target` And check if it is a checkbox or not.
- Change your selector from `".checktd"` to `"table tr"`. I would suggest you to use a more specific selector by adding class on `table` or on `tr`.

```js
$("table tr").on("click", function(e) {
  if($(e.target).is("input[type='checkbox']"))
    return;
  var check = $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]");
  check.prop('checked', !check[0].checked);
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:40%">
  <tr>
    <th>Check</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Telephone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td class="checktd"><input type="checkbox" class="checkItem"></td>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td class="checktd"><input type="checkbox" name="checkItem"></td>
    <td>Kevin Gates</td>
    <td>544444</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

**This will work for you**

I just removed this code - `if (this != e.target) { return; }` from your fiddle.

And for following the default action if you clicked on a `checkbox` I have used `event.target.type` for checking you clicked a `checkbox`, This worked fine for me.

```js
$(".odd").on("click", function(e) {
console.log(event.target.type);
  if(event.target.type != 'checkbox') {
    var check = $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]");
    check.prop('checked', !check[0].checked);
  }
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table style="width:40%">
  <tr>
    <th>Check</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Telephone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td class="checktd"><input type="checkbox" class="checkItem"></td>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td class="checktd"><input type="checkbox" name="checkItem"></td>
    <td>Kevin Gates</td>
    <td>544444</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: bro, now if i click on checkbox then it wont checked. i need both whatever clicks on tr or checkbox it will be selected. can u fix it?

Answer (score 0):

On click of `tr`  find the `input` element with `name` attribute and check if it is `checked`. If checked then uncheck it using `prop` else viceversa

```js
$("tr").on("click", function(e) {
  if ($(this).find('input[name="checkItem"]')[0].checked) {

    $(this).find('input[name="checkItem"]').prop('checked', false)
  } else {
    $(this).find('input[name="checkItem"]').prop('checked', true)

  }
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:40%">
  <tr>
    <th>Check</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Telephone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td class="checktd"><input type="checkbox" name="checkItem"></td>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td class="checktd"><input type="checkbox" name="checkItem"></td>
    <td>Kevin Gates</td>
    <td>544444</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the JsFiddle with Changes

```
$("table td").on("click", function (e) {
  if (this != e.target) { return; }
  var check = $(this).parent("tr").find("input[type=checkbox]");
  check.prop('checked', !check[0].checked);
});
```

[Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/kjr27r2j/9/)